# Best use of partials with tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, partials

For the sake of simplicity, let's say I have something like

```
<div class='important_class'>
    <%= @model.attribute %>
</div>
```

Imagine the `important_class` div was actually a large hierarchy of divs, and there was like 7 closing tags.  And now imagine I have 5 views that have the exact same look, besides the content in the center, where I might have `@model1.attribute`, `model2.attribute` and so on.  What's the best way of using partials in this case?

**Proposed solution 1**

Make 2 partials called `_top_part.html.erb` and `_bottom_part.html.erb` that contains the top part and bottom parts, and then use them in different views.  And the code would look like

```
<%= render 'top_part' %>
    <%= @model.attribute %>
<%= render 'bottom_part' %>
```

**Proposed solution 2**

In the controller level, pass a variable into the view to determine which partial to render, it will look something like

```
<div class='important_class'>
    <%= render @place+'_partial' %>
</div>
```

The reason why I don't like solution 2 is because the @place is too tightly coupled with the partials, and you might get weird behaviour with rendering the same view from many different controllers.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you models are different, you might just do

```
<div class='important_class'>
    <%= render @model %>
</div>
```

For example, let's say you have 2 models `Car` and `Bus`, it will look for 2 partials named `_car.html.erb` and `_bus.html.erb`

I'm not sure this is what you are asking though :-\

Comment: That's not what I'm really asking.  The `<%= @model.attribute %>` was more of an example.  It can be arbitrarily complex code in the body.